# Send Mail with email address in 4 columns

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I send email with Ron de Bruin's script where it has option for sending of email address from column B value.

I have at least 4 columns of email address from column B to E. How can I modify this to send this e-mail?

Example:

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

- In column A : Names of the people
- In column B : E-mail addresses
- In column C:Z : Filenames like this: `C:\Data\Book2.xls` (doesn't have to be Excel files)

The macro will loop through each row in `Sheet1` and if there is an e-mail address in column B and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = cell.Value
        .Subject = "Testfile"
        .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

        For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                    .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next FileCell

        .Send  'Or use .Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The title is a bit misleading and the info in the second line is mismatched as well. You say you have e-mail addresses from `B:E` but you also have filenames from `C:Z`. Is it safe to assume that you only have e-mail addresses in `B` and you the files you want to attach are in `C:Z`?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted without modifying the script, infact the email address are in col B:E and attachment in col F only.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. So, the way it works is, if `F` has an attachment and **ALL** of `B:E` has recipients, to send to all of these recipients?

Comment: Changed it as per your specs. See edited code below.

Answer (score 0):

**MASSIVE EDIT**

As per your comment, the code below is changed. Should be working under the assumption that there is a filename in Column `F`. The lines to remove/comment out are marked in the code below in case you don't want this requirement.

```
Private Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'--BK201 mod: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776481/send-mail-with-email-address-in-4-columns--'

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim Rec As Range, RecRng As Range, RecList As Range, RecMail As Range
Dim FileRng As Range
Dim RecStr As String

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set RecList = Sh.Range("B:B")
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each Rec In RecList

    With Sh
        Set RecRng = .Range("B" & Rec.Row & ":E" & Rec.Row)
        Set FileRng = .Range("F" & Rec.Row)
    End With

    RecStr = ""
    For Each RecMail In RecRng
        If RecMail.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            RecStr = RecStr & RecMail.Value & ";"
        End If
    Next RecMail

    If Len(FileRng.Value) > 0 Then '--Comment out if alright to send without attachment.
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .to = RecStr
            .Subject = "Testfile"
            .Body = "Hi " & Rec.Offset(0, -1).Value

            On Error Resume Next
            For Each FileCell In FileRng
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell
            .Display '.Send
        End With
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Else '--Comment out if alright to send without attachment.
        Exit For '--Comment out if alright to send without attachment.
    End If '--Comment out if alright to send without attachment.

Next Rec

Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

**Set-up:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Hope this helps. :)